# Objective-C, how to pass filenames to C function?

Tags: objective-c, c, arguments

I'm trying to pass an NSString to a C function, although it seems to not accept (or ignore) the parameters. Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

```
int copyfiles(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2 || argc > 3)
    {
        puts("usage: copy file [outfile]");
        return 1;
    }

    const char *infile = argv[1];
    char *outfile;
    if(argc > 2)
    {
        outfile = strdup(argv[2]);
        expect(outfile, "allocate");
    }
...
}

@implementation MyApplication 

@synthesize window;

    - (void)copy:(NSString *)pathToFile
    {
     NSString *pathToFile = @"/path/to/file";
     copyfiles((int)(const char *)[pathToFile UTF8String],(const char **)[pathToFile UTF8String]);
    }
```

I don't get any errors, but the output gives me "usage: copy file [outfile]", so I'm obviously not casting the parameters correctly.

Comment: Please don't cast char* to int.

Comment: All of the casting is wrong and that is why it doesn't give any errors — the casts lie to the compiler.

Comment: @Chuck — thanks; it's not easy to debug c code within objective-c evidently. i tried setting breakpoints and it wouldn't break either.

Comment: @JoeHabadas: Nah, that works fine. All C code is Objective-C code — it's not like you're embedding one language in another and it could work differently. Maybe you set the breakpoints too late in the function (i.e. after something had already gone wrong) or were accidentally not running a debug build or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your call to `copyfiles`, specifically *why* you're passing a string to a function that wants an integer for its first argument.

You need to pass that function an argument *count* followed by the pointer-to-pointer for the argument list.

For example, you would call it with the following C code (untested but you should get the general idea):

```
const char *args[] = {"copy", "fromfile", "tofile", NULL};
copyfiles (sizeof(args) / sizeof(*args) - 1, args);
```

The first line creates an array of character pointers (more correctly, C strings) including the NULL at the end which is mandated by the ISO C standard.

The second line passes two arguments, the first being the size of the array minus one (the number of "real" arguments in the list) and the second being the array itself.

In your particular case, where you seem to be using the one-filename variety, you should start with something like:

```
char *args[3];
args[0] = "copy";
args[1] = [pathToFile UTF8String]; // watch out for auto-release here?
args[2] = NULL;
copyfiles (2, args);
```

since your C function expects the `main`-like behaviour where the first argument is the "program" name.

Comment: i'm trying to adapt pass the NSString to (what's normally) a command line c function that's normally used like: `copyfiles file1 file2`

Comment: @Joe, I understand that. It's probably not the way I'd do it, preferring instead to just have a two-string version and not worrying about the count. However, having said that, what you're doing is possible but you need to follow the `main`-like conventions: the first argument is the number of items in the array of arguments and the second is the actual array itself. The way you're calling it is wrong. I'll update to clarify.

Comment: thanks for the example. I fixed a couple things on your code (changed ")" to "}" and added const in front of char), and it seems to pass the strings along now. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about you, but I would think the result of "`(int)(const char *)[pathToFile UTF8String]`" in your function call to "`copyfiles`" would be anything ***but*** 2 or 3.  Where did you find the sample code you're basing this implementation off of?

In any event, change that crazy cast to be a constant of 2 (since all you're passing is a single path) and see if you have better results.

Comment: normally the c function i'm trying to pass the NSString to is used from the command line. so it would normally want to be used like: `copyfiles file1 file2`

Comment: Look at your function declaration of "`int copyfiles(int argc, const char **argv)`".  It's an "`int`" followed by a "`char **`".  An integer followed by an array of char *'s.

Comment: so, it should be like `copyfiles(1,[pathToFile UTF8String])` or something?

Comment: yep... the first digit should be the number of paths you are passing along.  I think in your case it's always 1.